# Start date and End date DateDialogPickers

Tags: android

I have two DatePickerDialogs, one is for start date and one for end date. I need that every time the user open the end date Dialog the min date will be the start date dialog's date. Notice that the start date is not constant and the user can change it anytime.

Comment: Are you using `DialogFragment`?

Comment: Nothing yet i just dont understand how it can be done since the start date can be changed any time so the mindate for the end date DatePickerDialog needed to be set more than once.

Comment: Nope simple DatePickerDialogs which called from two different fragments: one for start date display and one for end date display(Two instances of same class).

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly. You should do something like this:

1. Get your start date `Calendar` instance.
2. Set your end date minimum date from start date `Calendar` instance.

   ```
   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
   ```